# Storage Chassis Rack Location

Tags: storage, rack, server-room, physical-environment, hardware

There are so many configurations of racks, it's not even funny.  Where do you guys keep your storage located?

I think the problem I'm having is that they're currently set too high in the rack and cold air isn't getting to them.  The cold air is short cycling from all of the servers with lower rack placement.

Should I give the storage its own rack on the other side of the room, put storage on the floor and blades/servers up high?  I've got about 70~80U of storage in a small room with about 14 racks (approx 4 racks wide and 4 deep with alternating hot/cold aisles).  Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail the problem that you're currently experiencing?  What type of storage are you using?  How hot is your storage running?  What is the ambient temperature on the cold aisles in your server room?  Are you concerned that warm exhaust air is getting drawn from the warm aisle over the top of the racks to the cold aisle?  Or is cold air short cycling through large gaps between storage mounted high and servers mounted low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the problem I'm having is that
>   they're currently set too high in the
>   rack and cold air isn't getting to
>   them.

With all respect, that makes logically zero sense.

You say further down:

> a small room with about 14 racks
>   (approx 4 racks wide and 4 deep with
>   alternating hot/cold aisles).

If you have proper hot / cold aisles (that are closed on top) then there is no way that hot air gets back into the cold aisle. No way like physically impossible.

If you do NOT have a proper cold aisle that is isolated - get one. Because with lots of racks and storage your run an energy density that you can hardly get cooled otherwise. Pump enough fresh / cold air into the cold aisle and you will get cooling.

Do not physically make air exchange impossible and you are wasting huge amounts of efficiency at the air flows you need there.

Comment: Even with hot/cold aisles, the cold air does not seem to make it up past 30U, there's a lot of stagnant air flow in several areas.  They are not closed on top, so that may be a portion of my problem.  I just started looking at some of the options available for purchase to solve some of these problems.